# http get in android

Tags: java, android, http, get, request

i have the following android code , i have an sms broadcast receiver in a service that waits for in coming sms, then on receiving it, it shows a toast, then it is supposed to make a get request to the specified url ,everything works as expected but the upload message action is not taking place, stumped here .

```
public class ReceiverContainer extends Service{

 public SMSreceiver mSMSreceiver;
 public IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    //SMS event receiver
    mSMSreceiver = new SMSreceiver();
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    // Unregister the SMS receiver
    unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
    mSMSreceiver = null;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
     public void Action(Context context,Intent intent) throws ClientProtocolException, URISyntaxException, IOException
        {
         Bundle myBundle = intent.getExtras();
         SmsMessage [] messages = null;
         String strMessage = "";
         String msgFrom = "";
         String msgText = "";

         if (myBundle != null)
         {
             Object [] pdus = (Object[]) myBundle.get("pdus");
             messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

             for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++)
             {
                 messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                 strMessage += "SMS From: " + messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                 msgFrom += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                 strMessage += " : ";
                 strMessage += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                 msgText += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                 strMessage += "\n";
             }

             Toast.makeText(context, strMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             uploadMessage(context,msgFrom,msgText);

         }
        }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
            try {
                Action(context,intent);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}

public void uploadMessage(Context context,String number,String msg) throws URISyntaxException, ClientProtocolException, IOException
{

    HttpResponse response = null;
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();


    Uri.Builder path = new Uri.Builder();
    path.scheme("http");
    path.authority("technonectar11.com");
    path.path("sms");
    path.appendQueryParameter("fromno" , number);
    path.appendQueryParameter("text" , msg);
    path.appendQueryParameter("uname" , "vijay");

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(path.build().toString());     
    //request.setURI(new URI("http://www.technonectar11.com/sms/insertsms?fromno="+number+"&text="+msg+"&uname=vijay"));
    response = client.execute(request);

    String result = convertStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());

    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    if (inputStream != null)
    {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try
        {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),1024);
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to make internet requests on the main thread.
Use [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to make the request.

Comment: i am using it as a service which has a process different than the main activity here, i used almost a similar service to send sms after receiving it from a http get request which worked fine, but it doesnt seem to work in the onReceive method of bradcast receiver somehow

Comment: thanks man, took me a whole lot of time and read throughs of the ddms console to get this, it gives me an "NetworkOnMainThreadException" which does not allow me to make that internet request. but i believe that IntentService does prevent this exception as it creates its own thread like AsyncTasks or Handler?

Comment: I see your point. Are you able to create an AsyncTask to do the task?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes, it now works, i used AsyncTask to handle the internet requests, which works well, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Declare **INTERNET PERMISSION** IN manfiest file

try HttpPost

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(URL);

     HttpResponse res = null;
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("asa "+res);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: already declared the internet permission, as for the receiver, since im using it dynamically, i didnt declare it in the manifest, but broadcast receiver works fine and receives sms, but im unable to update it using the http get request, will try to see if http post works